# How to do offline sync to LAN network when no internet connection

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

We know that in Xamarin.forms there is functionality of Offline Sync in conjunction with Azure Mobile App when no internet connection to the cloud.

We had this requirment where we are utilising Azure Mobile App as well as offline sync. But since the app will be sitting on multiple devices on the LAN network so it will be nice if the Internet is down and it falls back to LAN so each devices can talk each other on the LAN. Is this possible to achieve this Xamarin.Forms? The concepts is similar to Offline Sync.

I'm appreciated your feedback.

Thanks

Comment: Xamarin.Forms is *just* a UI Framework. How you handle your data doesn't have anything to do with it. - Azure Mobile Apps Sync relies on the Webservice Backend, which isn't available without the Cloud.

Comment: The only that we can think of is actually built a similar environment locally on LAN ie. web server that mimic the Azure Mobile backend ?!?!

Comment: That's one one option, but according to your question, it sounds like you want your devices in the LAN to be able to synchronize data between each other without an additional local server, right? So basically something like Git. Distributed data management is a really complex thing and I don't think you can get a usefull answer in the limited context of an Stack Overflow question.

Comment: That's exactly what we want ie. if the internet is down, devices in the LAN to be able to synchronize data between each other without an additional local server. We know that each devices has SQLLite on it. Any ideas how to achieve this then?

Comment: You can take a look at how GIT solves exactly this problem and build something similar (just way simpler^^). But it's a really sophisticated problem you are facing and you are propably going to spend some weeks on it. So better make sure it is an importand enough requirement.

Comment: Alternatively I guess just replicate Azure webservice plus the data as well in Local LAN. So the local LAN will have a webserver plus database server. The data and webservice code will get sync periodically.

Comment: https://github.com/mono/monotorrent/tree/master/src - have you looked at monotorrent sdk? This might help you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find devices and services in the local network you have to use something like [Zeroconf.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking)

You could have a look at https://github.com/onovotny/Zeroconf whether it fits your needs.